# change expresso store field with safecracker

Tags: expresso-store, safecracker

i want to change the price field from frontend , actually im templating like this but seems DONT WORK...  any help will be appreciate!!

```
{exp:safecracker channel="MY_CHANNEL" return="/PATH"  entry_id="{segment_3}"}

{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"} 
    <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="{price}" ></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" value="{sku}" ></td>
{/exp:store:product} 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `{exp:store:product}` tag inside an `{exp:safecracker}` tag, they do totally different things (the product tag is for creating add to cart forms).

You want something like this:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="MY_CHANNEL" return="/PATH"  entry_id="{segment_3}"}
    {field:product_details}    
    <!-- (or whatever you named your product details field) -->
{/exp:safecracker}
```